# Get grouped informations from an array with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataset structured like this:

```
"Date","Time","Open","High","Low","Close","Up","Down","Volume"
01/03/2000,00:05,1481.50,1481.50,1481.00,1481.00,2,0,0.00
01/03/2000,00:10,1480.75,1480.75,1480.75,1480.75,1,0,1.00
01/03/2000,00:20,1480.50,1480.50,1480.50,1480.50,1,0,1.00
[...]
03/01/2018,11:05,2717.25,2718.00,2708.50,2709.25,9935,15371,25306.00
03/01/2018,11:10,2709.25,2711.75,2706.50,2709.50,8388,8234,16622.00
03/01/2018,11:15,2709.25,2711.50,2708.25,2709.50,4738,4703,9441.00
03/01/2018,11:20,2709.25,2709.50,2706.00,2707.25,3609,4685,8294.00
```

I read this file in this way:

```
rows = pd.read_csv("Datasets/myfile.txt")
```

I want to get this information with pandas: for each day (so grouped day by day) get the first value of "Open", last value of "Close", Highest value of "High" and Lower value of "Low", and sum of Volume.

I know how to do with some for cicle, but it is a very inefficient way. Is it possibile to do with a few line with Pandas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `agg`:

```
df.groupby('Date').agg({
    'Close': 'last',
    'Open': 'first',
    'High': 'max',
    'Low': 'min',
    'Volume': 'sum'
})
```

Output:

```
            Close   Open    High    Low     Volume
Date                    
01/03/2000  1480.50 1481.50 1481.5  1480.5  2.0
03/01/2018  2707.25 2717.25 2718.0  2706.0  59663.0
```

Comment: @ gyx-hh, this is great and consize answer +1

Comment: I will mark as correct answer. Thank you dude. 
Another sub question. This group method, get the dates sorted in a strange way. There some way to get ordered in sequential time order?

Comment: @Steve you can sort the index... `.sort_index()`. But it should do that automatically in ascending order

Comment: Yes, But afer 01/01/2015 doesn't take 01/02/2015 but 01/01/2016!
This is numerical sort, not date sort! I want to perform a date sorting

Comment: Check the format of your date.. and covert it to datetime if need be. Using pd.to_datetime()